# Writing a React hook to handle multiple divs visibility on mouse click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Just started to learn about [Reack hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) but I cannot figure out if it is possible to write a simple hook (or should I use some other approach, e.g. `useEffect` along with `useState`) in order to control visibility of multiple elements by clicking on different buttons on page.

Let's say I have a simple app with 2 buttons and 2 "modal" windows:

```
const App = () => {
  const [firstModalOpen, toggleFirstModal] = useState(false);
  const [secondModalOpen, toggleSecondModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleFirstModal(true)}>Open First Modal</button>
      <button onClick={() => toggleSecondModal(true)}>Open Second Modal</button>

      <FirstModal
        {...props}
        show={firstModalOpen}
        toggleModal={toggleFirstModal}
      />

      <SecondModal
        {...props}
        show={secondModalOpen}
        toggleModal={toggleSecondModal}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const FirstModal = (props) => {
  const { toggleModal, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      { ...rest }
      show={firstModalOpen}
      onHide={() => props.toggleModal(false)}
    >
      First modal content...
    </Modal>
  )
}

const SecondModal = (props) => {
  const { toggleModal, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      { ...rest }
      show={secondModalOpen}
      onHide={() => props.toggleModal(false)}
    >
      Second modal content...
    </Modal>
  )
}

// state hook attempt

const useToggleModal = () => (init) => {
  const [show, setToggleModal] = useState(init);
  const toggleModal = () => setToggleModal(!show);
  return { show, toggleModal };
};
```

Since those are [`react-bootstrap` modal](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/modal/) windows, they use `show` and `onHide` properties to determine/handle visibility and I have to pass `rest` prop to avoid some side-effects.
If I'd use my hook attempt in my app, I'd handle both modals on any button click so I came up with the idea to pass a string (to both, buttons and modals) which would tell which modal exactly to handle, but that approach for some reason looked a bit wrong.

Is there a "smarter" way in React to handle this internally instead of passing strings around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple modals and only one of them needs to open at once, then you must use a single state which stores which modal is opened, kind of like a string having the id of the modal. However if you want to open multiple modals, you would store the isOpen prop differently

For the first case you would write your code like

```js
const App = () => {
  const [openModal, toggleModal] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleModal('first')}>Open First Modal</button>
      <button onClick={() => toggleModal('second')}>Open Second Modal</button>

      <FirstModal
        {...props}
        show={openModal === 'first'}
        toggleModal={toggleModal}
      />

      <SecondModal
        {...props}
        show={secondModalOpen}
        toggleModal={toggleModal}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const FirstModal = (props) => {
  const { toggleModal, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      { ...rest }
      show={firstModalOpen}
      onHide={() => props.toggleModal('first')}
    >
      First modal content...
    </Modal>
  )
}

const SecondModal = (props) => {
  const { toggleModal, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      { ...rest }
      show={secondModalOpen}
      onHide={() => props.toggleModal('second')}
    >
      Second modal content...
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

For the second case it would be as you have written in your example, the only optimisation you can do for the second case is to store an array of modal objects and render them dynamically or let each modal handle its own toggle states and use `useImperativeHandle` to provide methods which parent can call to child modals like

```
const App = () => {
  const firstRef = useRef(null);
  const secondRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.firstRef.current.toggleModal()}>Open First Modal</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.secondRef.current.toggleModal()}>Open Second Modal</button>

      <FirstModal
        {...props}
        ref={firstRef}
      />

      <SecondModal
        {...props}
        ref={secondRef}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const FirstModal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
 const { showModal, toggleModal } = useToggleModal(false, ref);

  return (
    <Modal
      { ...rest }
      show={showModal}
      onHide={toggleModal}
    >
      First modal content...
    </Modal>
  )
})

const SecondModal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const { showModal, toggleModal } = useToggleModal(false, ref);
  return (
    <Modal
      { ...props }
      show={showModal}
      onHide={toggleModal}
    >
      Second modal content...
    </Modal>
  )
})

// state hook attempt

const useToggleModal = (init, ref) => {
  const [show, setToggleModal] = useState(init);
  const toggleModal = () => setToggleModal(!show);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    toggleModal
  }))
  return { show, toggleModal };
};
```

Comment: The first example is exactly where I was heading, but was looking for something more like the second solution. Just to ask, shouldn't the second button use `this.secondRef` in `onClick` handler? Thank you very much for pointing out `useImperativeHandle`, that's probably exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Yes you are right, I updated my answer. That was a small copy paste error from my side

Comment: No problem :) Thank you one more time!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: Please consider  accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Ah sure, I upvoted but forgot to accept it, sorry :)